# Black screen after "Lock Screen"

Tags: 10.10, drivers, login-screen, i915

I'm using a new [HP Home G42-215BR](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=4325388) notebook, which uses an Intel HD Graphics GPU (i915 kernel driver).

My Ubuntu 10.10 installation is new and is up-to-date.

When I choose to lock screen in the menu and close the lid, if I reopen the lid within a short period of time everything works. But if it stays idle for a while and I reopen the lid, I don't get the login screen. All that I can see is a black screen with my mouse cursor. I can switch to tty1 (which works) with no problem, but switching back to `tty7` doesn't helps, I can't get the login screen anymore.

I don't want to have to reboot all the time I lock the screen... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it deserves a bug report in my opinion. For more on that, you can [take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but you can switch to a `tty`, and type : `ps -ef | grep tty7`. Remember the process ID (PID, so the first number on the first line with the coloured "tty7") and paste it in : `sudo kill -s 9 <the PID here>`. The computer don't reboot, just the session.